# Mails message contents not 'wrapping' (i.e. running off edge of box)

Tags: mail.app, email, formatting

I use OSX 'Mail' to look at my email.

I have received a message whose contents are not 'wrapping'.  Usually, when I resize a window the line breaks reformat so that all the message can be seen.  In this message the words run off the side of the window, even on full screen.[image]

I am running 0S 10.14.5 on a MacBook

Comment: Could you post the mail source on an innocuous email. mail > view > message > raw source  I suspect something in the html.

Comment: @historystamp - it's a big (school newsletter) email.  Do you need it all?  I'm not sure where to post it for you to see...?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113539/mail-in-mavericks-does-not-correctly-text-wrap-no-option-to-view-in-plain-text?rq=1

Comment: @dan post to guest on pastebin.com

Comment: @dan free HTML formatter. see: freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html  Post raw html here or pastebin.com.  FIle size doesn't make a difference.  Don't post personal information. You might want to edit out school name. I'll bet they are using fixed formatting or <pre>.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an HTML email has some CSS settings off the mark. Sender's fault. There is a little you can do. Hit <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and see it in an even worse format but at least the text lines would break way before the width ends.

The shortcut corresponds to View menu → Message → Raw Source.

Comment: Thanks, but not really any good - the message is thick with formatting info

Comment: My mistake, I posted the comment to the wrong place. Poof.  I didn't realize there were two answers.  I don't understand your comment about "out < and >".  It doesn't seem to me a mail user could implement this.  Is there a way to implement.

Comment: @historystamp I tried writing a simple buggy python code. https://pastebin.com/qBxwp1h4. But it makes interactive console in VSCode un-interactive when mail message is three pages long. Also, too much for a newsletter.

Answer (score 1):

This is an HTML part of a message formatted with an unprofessionnal client or directly from a software ill programmed (you can read the culprit name within the raw text source with `Mail` it should be within the header field `X-Mailer:` unless it is a really very bad software).

Unfortunatly, `Mail` doesn't provide any method to display such an ill formatted message as plain text. This is a serious problem since many attack E-mail (most notably phishing attacks) are using this technic to steal private information
or to make you connect on a booby trapped web server.

If you are worried by the global security problem of displaying E-mail messages as HTML, I would advise you to use a more professionnal E-mail client like `Thunderbird`:

https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/

In this case, you will be very easily able to display any suspicious E-mail as plain text, but not as raw source, i.e. a humain readable plain text:

```
View > Message Body As > Plain Text
```

[image: Thunderbird View Message Body drop down menu]

Another security function of `Thunderbird` is worth noting. When you are not sure of the true sender of an E-mail which can very easily be forged, it will enable you to display all headers which will train you to quickly recognize forged `From:` and `To:` headers:

```
View > Headers > All
```

Most of the time you will even see the IP address and the program used by the attacker.